# How to sort DropDownButton items?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I populate DropDownButton by xml nodes

```
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in kats.SelectNodes("Kats/Kat"))
{
btnKats.DropDownItems.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

And need to sort the items, somethig like:

```
btnKats.DropDownItems.Sort... // how can I do this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

But you can do this:

```
List<string> list = (List<string>) btnKats.DropDownItems;
list.Sort();
btnKats.DropDownItems = list;
```

The rationale is that DropDownItems is a ToolStripItemCollection that implements a plain IList (of objects). As objects are not naturally comparable, you can't sort an IList, but you can cast it to a List<string> and sort it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: Oh, three working solutions. But I can accept only one. Thanks a lot to everyOne.

Answer (score 3):

using System.Linq;

```
....

foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in 
    kats
        .SelectNodes("Kats/Kat")
        .OfType<System.Xml.XmlNode>() 
        .OrderBy( node => node.InnerText )
         )
{
  btnKats.DropDownItems.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

Don't have the compiler at hand and this line

```
 .OfType<System.Xml.XmlNode>()
```

could possibly be not needed. However, I am not sure whether or not `SelectNodes` returns `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` or just `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

Add on .OrderBy() to the end of SelectNodes()

```
   foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode node in kats.SelectNodes("Kats/Kat").OfType<XmlNode>.OrderBy(node.InnerText))
    {
        btnKats.DropDownItems.Add(node.InnerText);
    }
```

Edit: Wiktor is correct I beleive in neededing to add the .OfType so i am adding that in here also.